# Scala 2.11.6/slick 3.0.0-RC3/Eclipse IDE 4.0.0 Luna 22 parameter limitation

Tags: eclipse, scala, slick

I'm using Scala 2.11.6 , slick 3.0.0-RC3 and Eclipse IDE 4.0.0 build for the latest Scala version. Eclipse takes forever to compile the code with HLists.
Below is the code, Anyone's know how to fix this.

```
protected[vmi] class AccountConfigs(tag:Tag)
extends Table[AccountConfig](tag,"c_op_account")
{
def id = column[Long]("id")
def accountLocId = column[Int]("mfg_acct_loc_id")
def forecastLevel = column[String]("forecast_level_flag")
def orderPlanLevel = column[String]("order_plan_level_flag")
def runArimaFlag = column[String]("run_arima_flag")
def runCrostonFlag = column[String]("run_croston_flag")
def runETSFlag = column[String]("run_ets_flag")
def runTbatsFlag = column[String]("run_tbats_flag")
def runNnetFlag = column[String]("run_nnet_flag")
def minServiceLevel = column[String]("minimum_service_level_pct")
def orderMondayFlag = column[String]("order_monday_flag")
def orderTuesdayFlag = column[String]("order_tuesday_flag")
def orderWednesdayFlag = column[String]("order_wednesday_flag")
def orderThursdayFlag = column[String]("order_thursday_flag")
def orderFridayFlag = column[String]("order_friday_flag")
def orderSaturdayFlag = column[String]("order_saturday_flag")
def orderSundayFlag = column[String]("order_sunday_flag")
def historyForecastDays = column[Int]("max_history_length_days")
def ignoreAllDataBefore = column[java.sql.Date]("valid_data_start_date")
def warnFailForecastsDataExists = column[Int]("future__ongoing_gap_failure_flag")           
def warnFailForecastsDataNotExists = column[Int]("ongoing_gap_days_override")
def extrapolateData = column[BigDecimal]("largest_fillable_gap_pct")
def gapFillingDays = column[BigDecimal]("largest_ongoing_gap_pct")
def forecastConfidenceLevel = column[BigDecimal]("future__ss_forecast_confidence_level_pct")
def futureLiftConfidenceLevel = column[BigDecimal]("future__lift_confidence_level_pct")
def safetyStockForecastConfidenceLevel = column[BigDecimal]("future__ss_forecast_confidence_level_pct")
def safetyStockLiftConfidenceLevel = column[BigDecimal]("future__ss_lift_confidence_level_pct")
def customerSpecialOrder = column[String]("cso_detection_flag")
def cycleTime = column[Int]("cycle_time_days")
def minDaysOnHand = column[Int]("ss_min_days_on_hand")
def maxDaysOnHand = column[Int]("ss_max_days_on_hand")
def createTs = column[Timestamp]("create_ts")
def modifiedBy = column[String]("modified_by")
def * = (id :: accountLocId :: forecastLevel :: orderPlanLevel ::         runArimaFlag :: runCrostonFlag :: runETSFlag :: runTbatsFlag :: runNnetFlag :: minServiceLevel :: orderMondayFlag :: orderTuesdayFlag :: orderWednesdayFlag :: 
orderThursdayFlag :: orderFridayFlag :: orderSaturdayFlag :: orderSundayFlag ::
historyForecastDays :: ignoreAllDataBefore  :: warnFailForecastsDataExists  :: warnFailForecastsDataNotExists  :: extrapolateData  ::  gapFillingDays  :: forecastConfidenceLevel  :: futureLiftConfidenceLevel  :: safetyStockForecastConfidenceLevel  :: safetyStockLiftConfidenceLevel  :: customerSpecialOrder  :: cycleTime  :: minDaysOnHand  :: maxDaysOnHand  :: createTs ::  modifiedBy :: HNil).shaped <> (
{
case conf =>    AccountConfig(conf(0),conf(1),conf(2),conf(3),conf(4),conf(5),conf(6),conf(7),co   nf(8),conf(9),conf(10),conf(11),conf(12),conf(13),conf(14),conf(15),conf(16),con    f(17),conf(18),conf(19),conf(20),conf(21),conf(22),conf(23),conf(24),conf(25),co   nf(26),conf(27),conf(28),conf(29),conf(30),conf(31),conf(32))
                },{ 
                  AccountConfig.unapplied _ 
                }
             )
          }
```

Comment: For HList slow compile time... Have you tried to add types to intermediate steps and not do that in one step?

Comment: U have a link for it that i can follow?

Comment: This might be the cause: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8478 (I have no direct experience with `HList`s of this size, but creating two half of them and appending them together might help the compiler.)